# How to add multiple UIBarButtonItem on LEFT side of UINavigationBar with a BACK button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I'm able to follow http://blog.blackwhale.at/2009/06/uibuttons-in-uinavigationbar/ to add multiple buttons on the RIGHT side of the UINavigationBar.  However, I cannot find any solution to add multiple buttons on the LEFT side.  I want to add an "Edit" button next to the Back button in the UINavigation Bar for my iPad app.  It's kinda like the "Sign Out" and "Edit" buttons in the iPad YouTube app.

Anyone has any idea on how to implement it?

Thanks

Comment: you can add a segmentedcontrol that will have two options and add that segment control to your leftbar navigation item.

Comment: another option is you can hide your navigation bar and put toolbar there and on toolbar there will be no problem of adding multiple buttons

Comment: SegmentedControl doesn't work in my app.  I want the button effect because I want the "Back" and "Edit" button on the left and the "Add" button on the right side. Hiding the navigation bar might work because I haven't figured out a way to smoothly transition from a navigation bar to a toolbar during a "pushNavigationController" animation.  Also, I'm having trouble to create the buttons that works with the black bar style.

Answer (score 2):

```
 let editImage   = UIImage(named: "YourImageName1")!

 let searchImage = UIImage(named: "YourImageName2")!

let editButton   = UIBarButtonItem(image: editImage,  style: 
.Plain, target: self, action: "didTapEditButton:")

let searchButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: searchImage,  style: 
 .Plain, target: self, action: "didTapSearchButton:")

navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [editButton, searchButton]
```

And In the End Make Functions For Tapping Buttons

```
func didTapEditButton(sender: AnyObject)

{

 ...
}

func didTapSearchButton(sender: AnyObject)

{

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a UIView to the left side and add the buttons in programmatically, however there doesn't seem to be a better way. This may be how the tutorial you listed works, however I did not check. If you need a code example I can provide one.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem,

```
UIView *leftView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];

UIButton *myButton2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Main_Menu_SearchIcon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton2.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 70,30);
[myButton2 addTarget:self action:@selector(openSetting:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
myButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = myButton2.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;

UIButton *myButton3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Main_Menu_SearchIcon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton3.frame = CGRectMake(50.0, 0.0, 70,30);
[myButton3 addTarget:self action:@selector(openSetting:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
myButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = myButton3.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;


[leftView addSubview:myButton2];
[leftView addSubview:myButton3];
UINavigationItem *item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:self.tabBarItem.title];
    UINavigationBar *naviBarObj = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];
    naviBarObj.barTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    naviBarObj.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:item, nil];
    naviBarObj.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftView];
```